# Open embedded Visualforce charts in new window

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I have two embedded charts in a custom VF page that is then displayed on the Account detail screen. I'm passing the correct parameters and the reports work fine and display fine on the Account detail page.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <analytics:reportChart reportId="00Oi0000005jhBz" cacheResults="true" size="medium" filter="[{column:'Order.Account.Id', operator:'equals', value:'{!Account.Id}'}]"></analytics:reportChart>
</div>
```

What I would like to do, however, is instead have a text link and those reports open up in a new window. Can embedded charts open in a new window and I pass the correct parameters via the URL?

I can get the reports to display in a new window fine, but I am unclear how to pass the correct filters in my link so the reports actually display the correct data:

```
<a href="/apex/getIndustryAccountReports?vID={!Account.ID}" target="_blank">
```

Are there certain ways I have to do this, so that the reports in the new window get passed the correct filters?

Answer (score 1):

your Visualforce page can call on action

"init" would be a function on your controller like so:

```
public void init() {
  String vid = ApexPages.currentPage.getParameters.get('vid');
}
```

You can now use "vid" to embed the report in your visualforce page.